# aggregate json field names into array

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that holds JSON data. In a query with a `GROUP BY` clause, I'd like to get an array of all of the JSON field names in the result set.

I tried a query like this:

```
SELECT array_agg(jsonb_object_keys(data)) 
FROM table 
GROUP BY some_id 
WHERE some_id = 3
```

For an input data like

```
some_id | data
--------|---------------
3       | {"foo": "bar"}
4       | {"baz": 3}
3       | {"bar": 4}
```

I'd like to receive:

```
array_agg
--------------
{'foo', 'bar'}
```

But it returns an error: `ERROR:  set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set`

It seems like I need to somehow convert `setof text`, which is what `jsonb_object_keys` returns, into `array` but I don't know how.

Comment: something like `SELECT json_agg(data) FROM table`?

Comment: Please do [not crosspost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/157328). Already asked and answered here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/198098/1822

Comment: Sorry for the crosspost, I wasn't sure if the other exchange was as active as the normal.